# How to scan multiple QR codes in IOS app using BrowserStack App Automate tool?

Tags: qr-code, mobile-application, ios-ui-automation, browserstack, browserstack-app-automate

In IOS App automation using BrowserStack App Automate tool, need to scan multiple QR codes in one session. Currently, can scan only one QR code after injecting it before camera action. Can anyone help me with alternative for this?

Till now tried below things-
-Injecting QR code before camera action and open camera action on IOS app is scanning first QR code
-For second QR code, app is not recognising injected QR code

Answer (score 0):

I would request you to first follow this documentation- https://www.browserstack.com/docs/app-automate/appium/advanced-features/camera-image-injection

Also, I think this feature is still not there as it is not mentioned in their documentation to scan multiple images in one single session.

Also, please note that you may need to upload all those images to the BrowserStack server before starting your automation.

As a workaround maybe you can break your test into multiple subtests and for each image, you can run a new Brwoserstack session.

I would recommend you raise a support ticket with their support team, maybe as a feature request.

Link- https://www.browserstack.com/contact?ref=help#technical-support

I hope this helps.